# Subir un archivo a Firebase storage usando vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

Tengo un archivo html que recibe el archivo mediante un input

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-12">
  <label>Adjunte la copia de la cedula de conyuge en formato PDF</label>
  <input type="file" ref="cedulaTrabajador" @change="agregar" accept="image/jpeg" class="form-control" id="archivoCedulaConyuge"  data-validate="Anexe la copia de su cedula">
</div>
```

Quisiera si alguien pudiera indicarme como puedo subir a storage de firebase un archivo usando vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estas usando [vue-cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/) y [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/) necesitas instalar la libreria de [firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase) y configurar las credenciales de tu proyecto firebase en el archivo `/src/main.js` de la siguiente manera.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import firebase from 'firebase/app'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

// llenar con las credenciales de tu proyecto firebase
firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: '',
  authDomain: '',
  databaseURL: '',
  projectId: '',
  storageBucket: '',
  messagingSenderId: '',
});

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Después en el archivo `.vue`, donde esta tu input implementa un código parecido al siguiente:

> Nota: Para poder guardar archivos en `firebase storage` deberás configurar los permisos de escritura y lectura en tu proyecto `firebase`.

```
<template>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
    <label>Adjunte la copia de la cédula de conyuge en formato PDF</label>
    <input
      type="file"
      ref="cedulaTrabajador"
      accept="application/pdf"
      :disabled="loading"
      class="form-control"
      id="archivoCedulaConyuge"
      data-validate="Anexe la copia de su cédula"
    >
    <br>
    <button :disabled="loading" @click="agregar">Subir Archivo</button>
    <p v-if="downloadUrl">
      Archivo disponible en:
      <a :href="downloadUrl">Link</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/storage';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      loading: false,
      downloadUrl: ''
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async agregar() {
      try {
        const { files } = this.$refs.cedulaTrabajador;
        this.loading = true;
        const file = files[0];
        if (file) {
          const isPdf = file.type === 'application/pdf';
          if (isPdf) {
            const response = await firebase
              .storage()
              .ref(`pdfs/${file.name}`)
              .put(file);
            const url = await response.ref.getDownloadURL();
            console.log('archivo disponible en ', url);
            this.downloadUrl = url;
          } else {
            console.log('Archivo no valido');
          }
        } else {
          console.log('falta el archivo');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
      this.loading = false;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```